# Text isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

So I have a responsive page, and I can make it that a image disappears on a breakpoint, but when I try to set different text propertry for that breakpoint it won't work I'm new to html, css and responsive so I'd like some help on this

html:

```
    <div id="info">
    <h2>Wie zijn wij?</h2>
    <p>Van Vliet automatisering ontwikkeld database op maat,
       Binnen veel bedrijven word gewerkt met gegevens. deze gegevens worden nog al eens opgeslagen in een excel werkblad, Bij een kleine hoeveelheid gegevens gaat dit nog goed. Echter word het een probleem wanneer de hoeveelheid gegevens groeit,
       en wanneer er meerdere personen deze gegevens op hetzelfde ogenblik willen raadplegen en of wijzigen. Zo bereikten onze klanten ons met de vraag of er een betere en efficiëntere manier is om met data om te gaan. dit kan op verschillende wijzen en met behulp van verschillende programmeer talen zoals: VBA of VB.net.</p>
    <img src="Images/mbp.png">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </div>
```

the css:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    #info img {
        display: none;
    }

    #info p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

the css without breakpoints:

```
    #info p {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 1100px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    width: 700px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline;
    color: #FFF;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Does your `@media` query come before or after the non-breakpoint definition? I'm assuming it comes before - if so, try moving it after.

Comment: No it does come after, at the bottom of my css document also I've set the same propertys for my next breakpoint and it does work there?

Comment: Alright, then what you've given us works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWXGPW. Please give us code that demonstrates the problem so we have a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: In general RWD involves relative measurements (ex. `p { width:100%;}`) and absolute values as limits (ex. `p {max-width:700px}`). Your media queries can be more effective if you set it with just a max and follow up on another MQ with the min being it's max.

Comment: Also, you have a top margin on an inline `<p>` which ignores `margin-top` . `display:inline-block` should honor a `margin-top` if you remove the `float` (which you should because there are better alternatives than `float`.)

Comment: @zer00ne This comment fixed it, Thanks! also how do I remove the big white space next to my lay-out?

Comment: No problem, @LaurensvanVliet. I'm not certain what your environment entails (i.e. Wordpress,  webhost, etc.,) although I have an idea by the ruleset (i.e. `selector {property: value;....}`) that you are starting from scratch with no theme or boilerplate, just a blank page? If so, then you should use [normalize.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.css). It'll give you some workable default styles. If you don't use that for some reason, try this:`html, body {width:100%;height:100%; margin:0; padding:0}`  This is a reset of sorts. If you submit another question, I could...

Comment: ...answer it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is the Float right and the width. Check this and tell me.

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    #info img {
        display: none;
    }

    #info p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        float:inherit;
        width:auto
    }
}
```

Comment: That does it, but I can't seem to set the padding or margins for it I want to move it a bit down, and I don't want the width to be on the whole page... also there is a big white space next to the actual lay-out which you can scroll on to.

Comment: I need more information, make a fiddle or a codepen please.

Answer (score 0):

Write desktop style on top and media query/responsive styling below it and try float: none. 
Thanks

Comment: But I need that float on desktop because on the desktop there's a picture which I don't display on phone

Comment: I mean Try float none in responsive mode. Along with width auto property